# callback function for setState only fills the last component's state to parent component's state on render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a callback function in order to pass child component's state to parent components' state.

When all the child components load I want them to execute callback function and fill up the parent component's state.

Although only the last component seem to pass it's state to parent component.

---

My child component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Component(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    var index = props.index;
    var stateSchema = {};
    stateSchema[index] = state;
    props.updateState(stateSchema);
  }, [state]);

  function onLeftClick() {
    setState(state + 1);
  }

  return <p onClick={onLeftClick}>{state}</p>;
}
```

My parent component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Component from "./Component";

export default function ParentComponent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  function updateState(updatedState) {
    setState({
      ...state,
      ...updatedState
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Component index="a" updateState={updateState} />
      <Component index="b" updateState={updateState} />
      <Component index="c" updateState={updateState} />
      <Component index="d" updateState={updateState} />
      <Component index="e" updateState={updateState} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the console normally i should see,

`Object {e: 0, a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, d: 0}`

but i see,

`Object {}`

`Object {e: 0}`

Here is my working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-resonance-f085n?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I would appreciate any suggestion, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains. This is explained in the documentation of setState.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

So in your `updateState` function, when it get called, the state has not been updated yet.

```
function updateState(updatedState) {
    // state is {}
    setState({
      ...state,
      ...updatedState
    });
  }
```

To make it works, update your code like below:

```
function updateState(updatedState) {
    setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      ...updatedState
    }));
  }
```

More about this here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate